# crontabs hour specification */1 is that the same as *

Tags: linux, time, crontab, cronjob

I am looking for clarification with the cron tab that I am working with.

```
some job    1   *   *   *   *
some job    1   */1 *   *   *
```

Are those jobs the same? The job will run the first minute every hour.

Prehaps some one could clarify the difference between `*` and `*/x` in crontab.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes those are the same. From the man page (`man 5 crontab`):

```
A field may be an asterisk (*), which always stands for ``first-last''.
[...]
Ranges can include "steps", so "1-9/2" is the same as "1,3,5,7,9".
```

Therefore `*/x` means the whole range (depending on the position of the `*`) covered with steps of `x`.

In your case, for the "hour" position, the first-to-last range is 0 to 23. So `*` = `0-23`, and `*/1` = `"0,1,2,...,22,23"`, which is exactly the same.